# boolean flag value not preventing the recursion in trigger

Tags: trigger, recursion

I need to prevent the recursion in after update.
Can't use before update for some reason.
Kindly suggest why recursion is not getting prevented.

```
Public static Boolean flag=true;

if(flag){
flag=false;
List <Account> acclst =[Select Id ,Name ,Date__c,check__c from Account where  Id=:trigger.new AND check__c=:TRUE];

if(acclst != null && acclst.size()>1){
acclst[0].Date__c =acclst[0].Date__c-10;
}
update acclst;

}
```

Comment: I think we'll need some additional context for this code. Is this code in a trigger, or is it inside of an Apex class? If it's in a trigger, static variables inside of triggers are functionally useless. The value is reset between contexts (i.e. between `before update` and `after update`) and also between each chunk of 200 records. You probably also want to be using a `Set<Id>` instead of a single `Boolean` as the boolean would prevent the trigger from running on more than 200 records.

Comment: @DerekF...cud u please guide me how to do it through Set<Id> instead of using Boolean variable.Generally , recursion is prevented using Boolean variable thats y I have used it.

Comment: @DerekF yeah this is inside trigger code and not the Apex class code.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000332407&type=1&mode=1

Comment: This video shows ways to handle recursion including use of Set<Id> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amOhAqUaYoo

Comment: @ cropredy....@PranavParakh....finally due to Set<Id> my issue got resolved

Comment: @cropredy...@PranavParakh...thnx again